# Filtering by user role in js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have following [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-wave-lj5psn).

```
    export default function App() {
      const users = [
    { id: 34, name: "A", role: "pro" },
    { id: 43, name: "B", role: "customer" },
    { id: 35, name: "C", role: "pro" },
    { id: 55, name: "D", role: "pro" },
    { id: 67, name: "test", role: "pro" },
    { id: 543, name: "Jhon", role: "customer" }
     ];

     const customer = users.filter((u) => {
      return u.role === "customer";
     });

     const pro = users.filter((u) => {
    return u.role === "pro";
     });

    return (
    <div className="App">
      <Card role={"Customer"} count={customer.length} />
      <Card role={"Pro"} count={pro.length} />
    </div>
    );
    }
```

I am trying to filter users by their role and then I am showing the count of that role in `Card` component.

For every role I am writing filter function. That is working, but how can I improve my code for not repeating myself ?

Comment: Make a function that takes the role as argument and invokes `users.filter` with that?

Comment: I think yes, I need something like that

Comment: or just get all the `roles` from the users array and iterate over it? `const userRoles = new Set(users.map(({role}) => role));`

Comment: no, I need to get count of all `pro` users and count of `costumer` users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try creating one function which filters users by their role and returns an array of a particular user by role, here I tried you can take look into this.

```js
import Card from "./Card";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const users = [
    { id: 34, name: "A", role: "pro" },
    { id: 43, name: "B", role: "customer" },
    { id: 35, name: "C", role: "pro" },
    { id: 55, name: "D", role: "pro" },
    { id: 67, name: "test", role: "pro" },
    { id: 543, name: "Jhon", role: "customer" }
  ];

  const customer = checkUserByRole('customer');

  const pro = checkUserByRole('pro');

  function checkUserByRole(role) {
    const filteredUser  = users.filter((user) => {
      return user.role === role;
    });
    return filteredUser;
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Card role={"Customer"} count={customer.length} />
      <Card role={"Pro"} count={pro.length} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

}

Comment: thanks...your code is much more cleaner and understandable ...it works for me

Comment: I'm glad to hear that it's working well for you, have a great day.

Answer (score 1):

As @UnholySheep already mentioned in the comments, something like:

```js
function getUsersByRole(users, role) {
  return users.filter((u) => u.role == role));
}
```

Which you can then call for each role you want.

You could alternatively even use some sort of `groupBy` function, like the one from another SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34890276/15469537

```js
let groupBy = function(xs, key) {
  return xs.reduce(function(rv, x) {
    (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
    return rv;
  }, {});
};
```

And then simply call

```js
let grouped = groupBy(users, 'role');
// returns {pro: Array(4), customer: Array(2)}
```

Comment: For the count, just return `.length` of the result in the above functions

Comment: thanks... it works also , but Chaitya Panchal's code is much cleaner